# react-native-navigation showModal Custom Size

Tags: wix-react-native-navigation

I use wix react-native-navigation. Navigation.showModal open fullscreen size. Is it possible to open the custom size? where do I find all the properties list about navigation layouts? Documentation is too meager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal is always full screen. You can control your view's dimensions in jsx.
Instead of `flex: 1` - use a predefined width and height according to your needs.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{width: '80%', height: 150}}>
    { /* render Modal content */ }
    </View.
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to interact with the UI behind the Modal you should use a `Navigation.showOverlay`

```
Navigation.showOverlay({
  component: {
    name: 'example.Overlay',
    options: {
      overlay: {
        interceptTouchOutside: false // this make touch events pass through the invisible parts of the overlay
      }
    }
  }
});
```

For more examples on Overlay used you can see code examples in the [playground app](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/playground/src/screens/OverlayScreen.js)